# I am getting too many solutions when I need only one

Tags: sql, mysqli

I use a query that returns the name of the city with the highest number of orders placed.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT MAX(o.OrderID) AS [Number of Orders], od.ShipCity
FROM Orders o, [Order Details] od
GROUP BY o.ShipCity
ORDER BY [Number of Orders] DESC
```

I got all of the cities and their orders instead of just the one city with the most orders.

What happened?

Comment: You have not established a relation between your two tables, so you are starting with a Cartesian product. Have you considered **joining** the two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the highest orderID (MAX) per ship city rather then the count.
You instead need COUNT(o.OrderID)
And in MySQL you need to use LIMIT 1 on the end to get only the top most result.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there's a couple of things wrong with your query. First, you're getting the max order id , which is presumably some autoincrement column. It's like Karl's answer is first, mine is second, SELECT MAX(answerid) FROM this_discussion = 2.... but that doesn't mean I have more answers than he does.

Rnofx5 is also right... you need to tell your table what to join ON, cause right now it's creating a Cartesian Product. If you're not sure what that is, for now accept that it's a horrible, evil, wicked thing to do and then Google it after we're done fixing the query.

So, we have orders and order details. Presumably orders does not contain City, so we need order details

SELECT count(o.OrderID), od.ShipCity
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN [Order Details] AS od
ON o.{a varible that both Orders and Order Details have in common}  = .{a varible that both Orders and Order Details have in common}
GROUP BY od.ShipCity
ORDER BY count(o.OrderID) DESC
LIMIT 1;

Okay, so we're joining Orders with Order Details. In order to do that, we need to associate every order with something in Order Details. I don't know your schema, but from the sounds of it probably each order has a corresponding record in Order Details. In that case, you join these two tables using their ID. Something like

ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID

Now, we are counting all of the orders associated with a particular city... and we sorting them by our count, in descending order. And then we are keeping only the very first record that's returned (LIMIT 1)

Depending on your SQL implementation, you may need TOP 1 instead of LIMIT 1. You tagged mysqli, so presumably this is MySQL and in that case you'd want LIMIT not TOP. But be aware that that's a syntax variation you may encounter at some point